# Best way to take a 2d grid from standard input and create a 2-d array?

Tags: java

I am trying to take the standard input and create a 2-d grid with it.

The input will be:

```
n //number of rows and columns
aaaab
bbbba
aaaab
bbbaa
```

And I want to create a 2-d char array with those characters. I am drawing a blank on the most efficient way to do this. I know it can be done with a few different for loops, but I'm curious of a better way.

Here is what I have so far, just the beginning

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
 int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
 char[][] grid = new char[n][n];
```

Comment: dude just read it in, complexity wise there's no way it'll be faster than 2 for loops. The only difference you could make is in the data structure u use to store it, but that will depend on what you're using the data for.

Comment: Fair enough @softwarenewbie7331  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have them input a string.

string.toCharArray() and add that to a list...

```
char[][] d2char = new char[n][n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    string s = scanner.read();
    d2char[i] = s.toCharArray();
}
```

or if you have the strings somewhere else do the same thing just add the string as a character array to the char 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [as Ya Wang suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404633/4844216), read whole strings and convert them to char array. Second, way more important, use a **buffered reader**:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int n = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
char[][] grid = new char[n][];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   grid[i] = r.readLine().toCharArray();
```

Building a `java.util.Scanner` on `System.in` is easier to remember, but inefficient... Of course if you are manually inserting the grid line by line it will make no difference (as it will make no difference reading a whole line rather than a char at a time) but if you try to pipe a huge grid from a file and make some benchmarking you will notice the difference...